# Is HashMap internally implemented in Java using LinkedList or Array?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, hashmap, hashset

How is `HashMap` internally implemented? I read somewhere that it uses `LinkedList` while other places it mentions Arrays.

I tried studying the code for `HashSet` and found `Entry` array. Then where is `LinkedList` used?

Comment: Why did you look at `HashSet` when you wanted to learn about `HashMap`'s implementation? `HashMap` uses a linked list, but not the class `LinkedList`.

Comment: Read the source code? It's actually full of informative comments...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i am just going through the internal implementations of all collections, learning hashset along with hashmap is ok i guess

Comment: @Grammin: i am confused after reading that only..

Comment: @Grammin I find it amazing that article at no point includes the word "chaining". (It also kind of rambles on.) Also the premise of an interview question is subtly asinine. "How would you implement a hash table?" is a good interview question. "Explain, from memory, how Java implements `HashTable`" is silly. While there's some value in knowing these details when you **really** care about microoptimisation, there's no reason why you'd memorise them up front.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i am just going through the internal implementations of all collections , hashset was a typo. i meant hashmap only

Comment: If you are really curious, explore java.util.HashMap [java - download java source].

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It basically looks like this:

```
 this is the main array
   ↓
[Entry] → Entry → Entry      ← here is the linked-list
[Entry]
[Entry] → Entry
[Entry]
[null ]
[null ]
```

So you have the main array where each index corresponds to some hash value (`mod`'ed* to the size of the array).

Then each of them will point to the next entry with the same hash value (again `mod`'ed*). This is where the linked-list comes in.

*: As a technical note, [it's first hashed with a different function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364329/1711796) before being `mod`'ed, but, as a basic implementation, just modding will work.

Comment: Note that since java 8, the LinkedList in the bucket can be replaced by a TreeMap if it get too big. See here: http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/04/hashmap-performance-improvements-in.html

Comment: hash bins containing a large number of colliding keys improve performance by storing their entries in a balanced tree instead of a linked list. This JDK 8 change applies only to HashMap, LinkedHashMap, and ConcurrentHashMap. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html

Answer (score 9):

Each `HashMap` has an Array and in that Array it places each `Entry` in a position according to its key's hash code (e.g. `int position = entry.getKey().hashCode() % array.length`). The position where an `Entry` is stored is called a *bucket*.

If more than one `Entry` ends up in the same bucket, those Entries are combined in a `LinkedList` (also see @Dukeling's answer). Thus the bucket metaphor: each Array index is a "bucket" where you dump in all matching keys.

You have to use an Array for the buckets in order to achieve the desired *constant time* performance for random access. Within a bucket you have to traverse all elements to find the desired key anyways, so you can use a `LinkedList` as it is easier to append to (no resize needed).

This also shows the need for a good hash function, because if all keys hash to only a few values you will get long `LinkedList`s to search and a lot of (fast to access) empty buckets.

Answer (score 5):

HashMap has an array of HashMap.Entry objects :

```
/**
 * The table, resized as necessary. Length MUST Always be a power of two.
 */
transient Entry<K,V>[] table;
```

We can say that Entry is a one-way linked list (such HashMap.Entry linkage is called "Bucket") but it is not actually a java.util.LinkedList.

See for yourself :

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K,V> next;
        int hash;

        /**
         * Creates new entry.
         */
        Entry(int h, K k, V v, Entry<K,V> n) {
            value = v;
            next = n;
            key = k;
            hash = h;
        }

        public final K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public final V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public final V setValue(V newValue) {
            V oldValue = value;
            value = newValue;
            return oldValue;
        }

        public final boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
                return false;
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)o;
            Object k1 = getKey();
            Object k2 = e.getKey();
            if (k1 == k2 || (k1 != null && k1.equals(k2))) {
                Object v1 = getValue();
                Object v2 = e.getValue();
                if (v1 == v2 || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2)))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public final int hashCode() {
            return (key==null   ? 0 : key.hashCode()) ^
                   (value==null ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        }

        public final String toString() {
            return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
        }

        /**
         * This method is invoked whenever the value in an entry is
         * overwritten by an invocation of put(k,v) for a key k that's already
         * in the HashMap.
         */
        void recordAccess(HashMap<K,V> m) {
        }

        /**
         * This method is invoked whenever the entry is
         * removed from the table.
         */
        void recordRemoval(HashMap<K,V> m) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

HashMap internally uses Entry for storing key-value pair. Entry is of LinkedList type.

> Entry contains following ->
>
> K key,
>
> V value and
>
> Entry next  > i.e. next entry on that location of bucket.

```
static class Entry<K, V> {
     K key;
     V value;
     Entry<K,V> next;

     public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K,V> next){
         this.key = key;
         this.value = value;
         this.next = next;
     }
}
```

HashMap diagram -

[image: custom Implementation of HashMap]

From : http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/02/hashmap-custom-implementation.html

Answer (score 1):

The map is something that retrieves/puts a value based on a key since the key is mapped with that particular value.

[image]

But Internally, this mapping technique is slightly different.

1. This HashMap is defined as an array(Let's say for simplicity we have a size of 8).
   [image]
2. Hashing is done to the key to identifying the place of the array where that particular key-value pair is going to store.

   a. Key may be primitive type or object

   b. Get the hashcode based on the key (If an object, we should implement better hashcode and equal methods in their class)

   c. This hashcode makes the indexing and searching faster.

   d. Maths - 12112, Science - 23454, Tamil - 3222112, English - 3243212
3. We can't put that key-value pair into the index which we have as hashcode since it is greater than the length of the array. So we do mod to get the place of the array where we have to put the key-value pair.
   a. Maths will be in 12112 % 8 =  0

   b. Science will be in  23454 % 8 = 4

   c. Tamil will be in  3222112 % 8 = 0

   d. English will be in  3243212 % 8 = 6
4. If your look carefully, we have collisions in the 0th index. How can we solve this collision? We have to save both key-value pairs in the same index For that, they introduce Node or Entry.**Node has Key, Value, Hashcode and next node of that particular index.**

[image]

5. when we have collisions It will add up to the next node. So finally It would be like this.
   [image]
6. **The hashMap is nothing but an array of linked lists**. So each position has a linked list of the array to avoid collisions.

## After Java 8

This LinkedList mechanism is changed to balance Tree since the time complexity of searching in the linked list is O(n). We have to go one by one to find the exact element in the LinkedList. in the balance Tree, It will be O(log(n)).

**After Java 8, The hashmap is nothing but an array of balance Trees.**