# Problems with my implementation of a Java Hashmap

Tags: java, string-hashing

After doing research and looking up old posts for a while I realize that when you use a Hashmap or Hashtable in Java where Strings are the keys, the first "round" of hashing is applied to each String objects hashCode (apparently there is a second hash function that is applied to the result of `int hashCode()`), where by default `int hashCode()`has some relationship with it's callers location in memory (from what I read). With that being said, if I had a map with a developer defined class for keys, I read that I can override `int hashCode()` and use some distinct field(s) of my object to return the most unique int possible for each object. However, consider the code fragment below that contains arrays of primitive types.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class test
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        HashMap<char[], int[] > map = new HashMap<char[], int[]>();

        String s = "Hello, World";

        int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        map.put( s.toCharArray(), x );

        x = map.get( s );

        for ( int i : x )
            System.out.print( i );
    } 
}
```

The program crashes from a `NullPointerException` of course because `map.get( s );` returns null. I suspect that has happened because there are two different references between `map.put()` and `map.get()`. What I want the program to output is 1 2 3 4 5.

My question: How can I get the above code fragment to look up the keys by the value of the key vs the reference of the key? That is, how can I get the program to output 1 2 3 4 5?

Edit:
I am using the hashmap as a look up table. I am reading strings from a file and need a fast way to determine if the string I just read in is in the table or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Read somewhere that there are 2 rounds of hashing". No. If you want to see how Strings are hashed - go look at the code.
2. The basic contract of hash map is that it will retrieve items if the keys have the same hash and are equal by their `equals` function. Why do you think that `char[]` has an overridden `equals` that allows it to compare itself with Strings properly? Or even between each other? It does *not* override equals, and will only return true if it's the same instance.
3. You are using arrays for keys. That is *possible* but most senior devs will shout at you for that. There is no good way to compare them: Object.equals (that they use by default) means you cannot reproduce an array - you have to use the *exact same object*. Using Arrays.equals (or similar means to compare contents) will mean you have mutable objects as keys - **BAD**.

As per your comment I understand that you want to be able to edit the string. That's fine before you put it into the map. But **do not** change objects when they are keys in a map in a way that might change the hash code or equals. Best way to do this is to use a custom object. Arrays are not suitable for this.

If you *really* want to change the values on the fly while they're in a map - use a `BiMap` (or do what it does in `forcePut` yourself).

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer. Here is where I read that there was a second hash function. Maybe I misunderstood something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364134/what-hashing-function-does-java-use-to-implement-hashtable-class?lq=1

Comment: @user3270407 But that is true for *any* object, not just Strings. Simply because the output of `hashCode` is an arbitrary `int`, while the number of slots in a `HashMap` is smaller than the number of ints. The second step is *specific to the map* and will happen *for any object inserted*. In fact, in many naive maps it's a simple `mod`

Answer (score 3):

Just use the String as the key for the map.

```
HashMap<String, int[] > map = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
String key = "array1";
int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
map.put( key, x );
```

String is immutable so it is good choice as the key for a map.

Adding another array:

```
String key2 = "array2";
int x2[] = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
map.put( key2, x2 );
```

Outputting values:

```
x = map.get( key );
for ( int i : x )
    System.out.print( i + " " );
}
```

gives

> 1 2 3 4 5

```
x = map.get( key2 );
for ( int i : x )
    System.out.print( i + " " );
}
```

gives

> 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One of the smallest changes you can do is to simply save your `char[]` before calling `put()`, and use the same one as argument to `get()`:

```
char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
map.put(charArray, x);
x = map.get(charArray);
```

The important thing here is that you need to use the same object to `get()` as you used to  `put()`.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle Documentation

```
public V get(Object key)

Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this 
map contains no mapping for the key.
More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v 
such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; 
otherwise it returns null.
```

and obviously s.equals(s.toCharArray()) is false. They are not even the same Class.

However, you could use as key a Class that overrides equals() in a way that returns true for your case.
For example:

```
class MyCharArray {

   private char[] data;

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (o instanceOf String) {
           return data.equals(o.toCharArray);
       else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: While it's true that this equals will return false, it's *not* a necessary precondition that objects need to be "the same object" or even "the same class" for it to return true.