# Hash an 8 digit number that contains non repetitive digits from 1 to 8 only

Tags: hash, hashset

Given that a number can contain only digits from 1 to 8 (with no repetition), and is of length 8, how can we hash such numbers without using a `hashSet`?

We can't just directly use the value of the number of the hashing value, as the stack size of the program is limited. (By this, I mean that we can't directly make the index of an array, represent our number).

Therefore, this 8 digit number needs to be mapped to, at maximum, a 5 digit number.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364329/5345646) answer. The `hash` function returns a 8-digit number, for a input that is an 8-digit number.

So, what can I do here?

Comment: What digits are you talking about? `I saw this answer. The hash function returns a 8-digit number` Hashing algorithms output a number of bits or bytes, not digits. How many bits do you need?

Comment: you cant fit 8 bits in 5 bits

Comment: @tkausl 16 at max.

Comment: @CasBloem I know that. But here the total permutations are 8! = 40320<1e6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you can do.  You could subtract 1 from each digit and parse it as an octal number, which will map one-to-one every number from your domain to the range [0,16777216) with no gaps.  The resulting number can be used as an index into a very large array.  An example of this could work as below:

```js
function hash(num) {
  return parseInt(num
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(x => x - 1), 8);
}

const set = new Array(8**8);
set[hash(12345678)] = true;
// 12345678 is in the set
```

Or if you wanna conserve some space and grow the data structure as you add elements.  You can use a tree structure with 8 branches at every node and a maximum depth of 8.  I'll leave that up to you to figure out if you think it's worth the trouble.

---

**Edit**:
After seeing the updated question, I began thinking about how you could probably map the number to its position in a lexicographically sorted list of the permutations of the digits 1-8.  That would be optimal because it gives you the theoretical 5-digit hash you want (under 40320).  I had some trouble formulating the algorithm to do this on my own, so I did some digging.  I found this [example implementation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-rank-of-a-string/) that does just what you're looking for.  I've taken inspiration from this to implement the algorithm in JavaScript for you.

```js
function hash(num) {
  const digits = num
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .map(x => x - 1);
  const len = digits.length;
  const seen = new Array(len);
  let rank = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    seen[digits[i]] = true;
    rank += numsBelowUnseen(digits[i], seen) * fact(len - i - 1);
  }

  return rank;
}

// count unseen digits less than n
function numsBelowUnseen(n, seen) {
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(!seen[i]) count++;
  }
  return count;
}

// factorial fuction
function fact(x) {
  return x <= 0 ? 1 : x * fact(x - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[kamoroso94](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2727710/kamoroso94) gave me the idea of representing the number in octal. The number remains unique if we remove the first digit from it. So, we can make an array of length `8^7=2097152`, and thus use the 7-digit octal version as index.

If this array size is bigger than the stack, then we can use only 6 digits of the input, convert them to their octal values. So, `8^6=262144`, that is pretty small. We can make a 2D array of length `8^6`. So, total space used will be in the order of `2*(8^6)`. The first index of the second dimension represents that the number starts from the smaller number, and the second index represents that the number starts from the bigger number.